# .hide() works but then shows previous animation?

Tags: jquery

I have an issue where my animations work perfectly, however when the .hide(); is triggered it just reverts back to the slideDown(); function.

I'm scratching my head over it, though i'm assuming it's running the animation because the previous click is still active?

```
$('div.SocialShareJob').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('p').slideUp(300).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).find('.Icons').slideDown(500).fadeIn(900);
});
$('div.CloseSharing').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('div.Icons').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Do you have overlapping divs? Are these `on` definitions called in a function multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the animations that haven't completed, and clear the queue:

```
$('div.CloseSharing').on('click', function(event){
    $(this).parent('div.Icons').stop(true).hide(); 
});
```

If the `closeSharing` div is a child of the other one, you may also need to stop the `click` event from propagating to the parent. To do this, add `event.stopPropagation()` to the start of the event handler:

```
$('div.CloseSharing').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('div.Icons').stop(true).hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for `stopPropagation`, now I should delete my answer  :)

Comment: Hope I didn't tread on your toes there - I'd started writing the edit before your answer came through!

Comment: Guys, thanks so much! Didn't know about event.stopPropagation(); that was the issue! It was propagating the parent. Top guys!